# How do we calculate the inverse Laplace transform of $F(s)=\frac{s^2+1}{(s+1)(s-1)}$?

Tags: partial-fractions, inverse-laplace

We have

\begin{equation}
F(s)=\frac{s^2+1}{(s+1)(s-1)}
\end{equation}

which I want to use Heavisde method to find the fractions.

We start

\begin{equation}
F(s)=\frac{s^2+1}{(s+1)(s-1)}=\frac{A}{(s+1)}+\frac{B}{(s-1)}
\end{equation}

By Heaviside method, we multiply both sides by the denumerator of A, ($s+1$)

\begin{equation}
(s+1)\frac{s^2+1}{(s-1)}=A+\frac{B(s+1)}{(s-1)}
\end{equation}

We insert for the pole of the A-fraction, for s, that is $s=-1$ and we obtain

\begin{equation}
(-1+1)\frac{s^2+1}{(s-1)}=A+\frac{B(0)}{(-2)}
\end{equation}

which gives the incorrect results, that $A=0$

What should I do here to prepare the fractions correctly for the Heaviside method to be applied?

Thanks

**Update**, I devise the method suggested below in the accepted solution, and try the Heaviside method  on that.

\begin{equation}
F(s)=\frac{s^2+1}{(s+1)(s-1)}=\frac{(s^2-1)+2}{(s+1)(s-1)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
F(s)=\frac{(s^2-1)+2}{(s+1)(s-1)}=\frac{(s+1)(s-1)+2}{(s+1)(s-1)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
F(s)=\frac{(s+1)(s-1)+2}{(s+1)(s-1)}=\frac{(s+1)(s-1)}{(s+1)(s-1)}+\frac{2}{{(s+1)(s-1)}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
F(s)=1+\frac{2}{{(s+1)(s-1)}}
\end{equation}

So from here we treat the last fraction with the Heaviside method:

\begin{equation}
F(s)=\frac{2}{{(s+1)(s-1)}}=\frac{A}{(s+1)}+\frac{B}{(s-1)}
\end{equation}

Find A by multiplying with $(s+1)$ on both sides and obtain

\begin{equation}
(s-1)=A+\frac{B(s+1)}{(s-1)}
\end{equation}

Insert for the pole of the A-fraction, $s=-1$

\begin{equation}
(-1-1)=A+\frac{B(-1+1)}{(s-1)}
\end{equation}

This yields that $A=-2$. We do the same for B,

\begin{equation}
(s+1)=\frac{A(s-1)}{(s+1)}+B
\end{equation}

Insert for $s=1$, and get that $B=2$, hence:

\begin{equation}
F(s)=1+\frac{2}{(s-1)}-\frac{2}{(s+1)}
\end{equation}

Inverse transform of F(s):

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{1+\frac{2}{(s-1)}-\frac{2}{(s+1)}\}=\delta(t)+2e^{t}-2e^{-t}
\end{equation}

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition works for proper rational functions (meaning that the degree of the numerator is strictly smaller than that of the denominator).

Comment: Thanks, this was entirely new to me,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

To start with, notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{s^{2} + 1}{(s-1)(s+1)} & = \frac{(s^{2} - 1) + 2}{s^{2} - 1}\\\\
& = 1 + \frac{2}{s^{2} - 1}
\end{align*}

Once you have done so, observe that
\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{s^{2} - 1} & = \frac{(s + 1) - (s - 1)}{(s-1)(s+1)}\\\\\
& = \frac{1}{s - 1} - \frac{1}{s + 1}
\end{align*}

Gathering all the previous results, it results that
\begin{align*}
\frac{s^{2} + 1}{(s-1)(s+1)} = 1 + \frac{1}{s - 1} - \frac{1}{s + 1}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: It did indeed. Have a look a the original post now! Thanks!

Comment: @Luthier you are welcome ! I am glad I could help.